# GroupFooter from FastReports not getting data using DBX instead of ADO in delphi

Tags: delphi, fastreport

Since I don't want to use ODBC connections anymore, I'm trying to get DBX work for my reports. Almost everything works the same as it worked with the tfrxAdoQuery, but not the GroupFooter.

I used to have a MasterData that used a ADOQuery1: TfrxAdoQuery and I changed to a DBXQuery1:TfrxDBXQuery.  Its fields like [BDXQuery."name"] work fine now than I'm using a different type of query, but only inside the MasterData. This is the way it looks in the MasterData and when the report is displayed it comes correctly:

[image]

For some reason, the Footer's tfrxMemoViews dont show the DBXQuery1."anyField" that I try to display. 
This is the way it looks in the footer but in the report just dont show the name.

[image]

The difference is the DatasetName can't be set for the DBXQuery (as it was set when using the ADOquery). When I was using ADO, the DatabaseName seem to be assinged arbitrarilly with a name like 'header' which did not belong to any component or variable. Now it should be more manageable since the fields that are set are DataSet (wich can be chosen from a group that has all the DataSets, in my case I can choose DBXQuery1) and DataField, which can be chosen from one of the predetermined fields that are in the DBXQuery1.

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated